# Lifespan of chicken stock in fridge

Tags: chicken, stock, chicken-stock

I boiled some chicken last week, and saved the stock for future use. But, as I don't have enough freezer space, I just put it in the fridge, so it has been liquid.

Since, it has been a week, is it still safe to use?

Thanks!

Comment: This is answered in [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/21068) (see "cooked dishes").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chicken broth is one of the most perishable foods there is—it is nearly a perfect growth medium.

The [FDA](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/factsheets/Chicken_from_Farm_To_Table/index.asp) recommends storing it no more than 3-4 days.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend only keeping chicken stock two or three days after cooking - much like cooked chicken itself.

If your stock was made with vegetables, I would keep it for even less time - not because of safety, but because vegetable stocks quickly turn bitter.